# How to modify content of an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps-api-3, syntax

I'm using the Google Maps API to create some zones on a map. I stored the geodata in a database and I get it through Ajax.

Problem is that API wants the data as an object like :

```
var myHome = { "lat" : "44.767778" , "long" : "-93.2775" };
```

So I need to put in the array the {"lat" : and "long : ... };

How could I do that ?

---

Here is what I did with your help. I've got no error but nothing appears on the map. I used the example with BermudaTriangle from the API like a model : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-autoclose

```
    $.get(
    "getZones.php", //Get geodata from database
    function(data) {
      locZone = data;
      var reg=new RegExp("[/]+", "g"); //Separate points of the zone
      var tableau=locZone.split(reg);
      for (var i=0; i<tableau.length; i++) {
          points = new google.maps.LatLng(tableau[i]);
          coords.push(points);//Put the coordinates in a tab
        }
      var zone = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: coords, //Use the tab like in the example from API
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 3,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35
      });
      zone.setMap(map);
    }
  );
```

---

That's okay I just rewrote the loop :

```
for (var i=0; i<tableau.length; i++) {
      var b=tableau[i].split(","); //Separate lat & lng
      points=new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(b[0]), parseFloat(b[1])); //Convert data into float type
      coords.push(points); 
    }
```

Comment: Please show some sample, how is your data stored/represented

Comment: A [google.maps.LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) is `{lat: Y.YY, lng:X.XX }`, not `{lat: Y.YY, long:X.XX}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also create a `LatLng` object directly through google maps api:

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.767778, -93.2775);
```

That returns the object what you need to work with the maps.

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way (without seeing any example code of you) is by putting the values you get via ajax in a new variable. Let's say the object you get is called geoData. geoData should have the 2 values lat and long or however you called them.

Simpliest way would be:

```
var myHome = {
    "lat": geoData.lat,
    "long": geoData.long
}
```

That's it, hope this helps.